# php ajax quota system

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to develop a tool to show my sales team where they are in the month towards their quota. 
I have their quota divided up into business days already but I want to be able to show them how close they are to their quota as a sale hits, so they place a sale and it updates the chart automatically.

I have this working as a snap not, hit refresh and reloads data but I'm then planning to stream this into their sales room ( so hitting refresh isn't an option).

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a question.

Comment: @andrewsi I agree, OP only posted statements, and not even statements that elicit responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need a mechanism to automate the refreshing for the data.

In that case you can use either meta refresh or a javascript refresh or ajax.

Meta refresh can be done as below.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

The above code will refresh the page in every 5 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
 }, 5000);
```

This also will refresh the page every 5 seconds.

Or else use the jQuery Ajax to call your results page into another page. For example if your results page name is tables.php, then the code would be as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#responsecontainer").load("tables.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#responsecontainer").load('tables.php?randval='+ Math.random());
   }, 5000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="responsecontainer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

cache:false is needed for IE fix

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, i think i have been coding too many hours i was getting in deep, and not looking for simple solutions anymore :) thanks again